# Почему меняется значение sentense.words[0]?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct word{
    char* syms;
};

struct sentense{
    struct word** words;
};

int main(){

    struct word word;
    struct sentense sentense;
    word.syms = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    sentense.words = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));

    word.syms[0] = '1';
    word.syms[1] = '2';
    sentense.words[0] = word.syms;

    word.syms[0] = '4';
    word.syms[1] = '5';
    sentense.words[1] = word.syms;


    printf("%s",sentense.words[0]);
    printf("%s",sentense.words[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

Почему выводится 4545, а не 1245?

Comment: Потому, что оба указателя `sentense.words[0]` и `sentense.words[1]` указывают в одно и то же место -- `word.syms`. Вот здесь -- `sentense.words[0] = word.syms;`, никакого **копирования содержимого** `word.syms` **не происходит**

Comment: не подскажете, а как тогда записать в `sentense.words[0]` содержимое `word.syms`, затем поменять содержимое `word.syms` и записать новое содержимое в `sentense.words[1]`, чтобы `sentense.words[0]` не поменялся?

Comment: [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup). Только не забывайте писать 0 после всех символов в `word.syms[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223603/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sentense-words0#comment2141670_1223603) @avp, можно использовать [strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

Не забывайте, что важно освобождать всю выделенную через `malloc()` память в конце программы используя [free()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free), я для простоты и демонстрации не делал этого, т.к. не делали это и вы, но освобождать всегда очень важная практика!

Полный доработанный вариант вашего кода:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##pZLRTsMgFIbv@xQnW8xo45qy6FXnXsR4USnbSChdgMao2bNXDmW13VqNkQsgP//5@Q6BrZks1KFtl0Ix2ZQctsaWok6Pu2gkSfF6rWmhDqhFbtswC2@1Lj8jcIMdCw0JmPfK5NE57x2GK8uV4Z1rUAZJ4tdgF8pCVQhF4lsnTvlQvYT2GxeAx2hMEQGegHREcVVIWTNCswzxxAev9/4ojkNkiEg9DBaOIScDBpYEg8a3P2cvLmdFV/mVTr2@udE3qGdTPF3UGOlCFFhQnG7GFa934TlcQtmcSH/nHPTDDPTjX6Dpf6Dp79An9w/tnizuzOJ@rucQ/pOVflu9V3PbaIU9ndv2Cw)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word{
    char * syms;
};

struct sentense{
    struct word ** words;
};

int main(){
    struct word word;
    struct sentense sentense;

    word.syms = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    sentense.words = (struct word **)malloc(100 * sizeof(struct word*));

    word.syms[0] = '1';
    word.syms[1] = '2';
    word.syms[2] = 0;
    sentense.words[0] = (struct word *)malloc(sizeof(word));
    sentense.words[0]->syms = strdup(word.syms);

    word.syms[0] = '4';
    word.syms[1] = '5';
    word.syms[2] = 0;
    sentense.words[1] = (struct word *)malloc(sizeof(word));
    sentense.words[1]->syms = strdup(word.syms);

    printf("%s", sentense.words[0]->syms);
    printf("%s", sentense.words[1]->syms);

    return 0;
}
```

Выход:

```
1245
```

Comment: А вот это -- `sentense.words[0] = (struct word *)malloc(sizeof(word));` для утечки памяти? Кстати, перед `sentense.words[0]->syms = strdup(word.syms);` необходимо написать `word.syms[2] = 0;` (чтобы strdup знала где остановиться)

Comment: @avp Почему для утечки памяти? Если быть корректным то в коде автора уже утечка была изначально, т.к. нет нигде очистки, и я в ответе написал комментарий, что мол очищать всегда нужно. Также в коде автора внутри sentense структуры был именно `word**` а не `char**`, поэтому я сделал у себя тоже `word**`, на случай того если в структуру слова ещё поля добавят это может пригодиться. Также в коде автора ошибка, он этому `word*` присваивал напрямую указатель `char*`, конечно код отработал, но формально нужно ещё доп уровень вложенности, что я и сделал с доп аллокацией под слово.Чистить надо конечно

Comment: Да, вы правы, утечки тут нет (не заметил добавленный уровень косвенности).